Не пишет градусы и состояние погоды
Не понимаю в чём проблема, я новичок и начал изучать питон 2 дня назад. Делал всё по видео, помогите, пожалуйста. Пока писал код вообще перестал работать, теперь бот не отвечает.
Код таков:
from aiogram import Bot, types

from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher

from aiogram.utils import executor

import python_weather

bot = Bot(token="Мой токен")

dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])

async def process_start_command(message):

    async with python_weather.Client(format=python_weather.IMPERIAL, locale="ru-RU") as client:
   
        weather = await client.find("Краснодар")
   
    celsius = (weather.current.temperature - 32) * 5 / 9
    

    resp_msg = weather.location_name + "\n"
    resp_msg += f"Текущая температура:{celsius}\n"
    resp_msg += f"Состояние погоды: {weather.current.sky_text}"

    await message.answer(resp_msg)
    #await client.close()

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo_message(msg: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, msg.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    executor.start_polling(dp)


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Можете конкретно привести команды, которые вы давали боту и то, что у вас было в консоли и в чате с ботом?

Всё что я писал боту - бессмысленные слова( в его коде прописано, что он должен отвечать тем же сообщением, что ему и написали. Если нужно привести пример, то это слова по типу - 1, аб, ало). Также я писал ему города ( Москва и Краснодар). Бот должен уметь отвечать на эти слова - какая температура в данном городе и его погода
